# Discovering and Connecting to a BLE device

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I think this question has been asked in different forms but there is no clear answer.
I want to be able to discover all available BLE device and connect to any of them. My peripheral device advertises a certain service. I read about 32feet.NET library and tried to use it but apparently it does not support BLE, and the only way I can scan my device through this library is to connect to windows first and then do the discovery.
I also went through this article: [Acuire data by C# from BLE](http://www.orcs.sebsoft.com/index.php/79-vision/72-how-to-acquire-data-by-c-from-bluetooth-4-bluetooth-low-energy-ti-ble-keyfob-ti-sensor-tag) but it didn't work for my device and I couldn't do any scanning. I even bought TI BLE dongle and tried their sample app: [TI sample app](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category%3aHealthDemo) but it didn't work with my peripheral device.
Then I tried to use Windows 8 sample code for BLE [Heart-rate app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95/view/Discussions) it worked fine with a heart rate BLE sensor, but still I couldn't get it to work with my peripheral device.

I thought there is a problem with my device but there is an app in iPhone called LightBlue which discovers BLE devices and can act as a peripheral device too, I even used that app but couldn't get it to work with Windows.

So my question is, is there any way or library or anything for C# that I can use to scan BLE devices and connect to them and send/received date?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?  I'm fighting a similar battle with a Bluetooth LE device on Windows 8.1 and I'm stuck.  Perhaps we can compare notes?

Comment: For those who're looking for the answer, I'd say there is not a library for Windows for this purpose. I'm talking about windows 7 and below, not sure about windows 8 and 10

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a library for Windows Form styled programs, however, Universal Windows Apps have the [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.aspx) namespace which will allow you to do everything you described (it's a little rough around the edges, though).